# Encode file path properly using python

Tags: python, url-encoding

I am trying to open files by getting the path from a dictionary. Some of the file names have commas (,) and other such characters which when used give a "no such file found error"

For instance the following file path will not open: `foo,%20bar.mp3`

If characters like commas exist then it should be encoded as : `foo%2C%20bar.mp3`

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: why is space represented as `%20` and not comma? Is the string supposed to be `foo, bar.mp3`?

Comment: The comma should actually have been %2C. But I am parsing an XML file and storing the results in a dictionary. In the XML file most of the paths ARE encoded but the there was one file with a similar pattern. Spaces were encoded, commas were not. Weird.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may need `pathname2url`

Python 2.x ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url))

```
>>> from urllib import pathname2url 
>>> pathname2url('foo, bar.mp3')
'foo%2C%20bar.mp3'
```

Python 3.x ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.pathname2url))

```
>>> from urllib.request import pathname2url
>>> pathname2url('foo, bar.mp3')
'foo%2C%20bar.mp3'
```

Comment: The function seems to be in urllib.request (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) now.

Answer (score 3):

```
from urllib import pathname2url
pathname2url('foo,bar.mp3')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use urllib. The following example might need to be changed if you use Python 3.x, but the general idea is the same:

```
import urllib

encoded_filename = urllib.quote(filename)
f = open(encoded_filename)
```