# escape whitespaces in linux path and file names

Tags: python, regex, file

i actually cleaning up my system. And as usual i am trying to do it the python way,
so i am cleaning up duplicates in my Music library. And now i am trying to find a pattern
for re module to escape all whitespace and special characters. But unfortunately i was unable to find something useable. This is some snipped of the duplicates list i generated with linux cli tool called "fdupes" :

```
./D/dominik eulberg/01 bionik/01 bionik (guy gerber remi.m4p
./D/dominik eulberg/05 dominik eulberg/01 bionik/01 bionik (guy gerber remi.m4p

./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/05 - Stars.mp3
./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/NOW - smokers delight_04.MP3

./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/13 - What I'm Feelin (Good).mp3
./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/NOW - smokers delight_13.MP3

./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/16 - Gambia Via Vagatorbeach.mp3
./N/Nightmares On Wax/Smokers Delight/NOW - smokers delight_16.MP3
./S/Stupidozid/Morast_Beatz/12. Morast Beatz - RAF - von TeeK.mp3
./S/stupidozid_12/Morast_Beatz-Startproblem_und_Endloesung_2012/12. Morast Beatz - RAF - von TeeK.mp3

./S/Slackers/Folder.jpg
./S/Slackers/AlbumArt_{4CC84D50-8EED-415A-9ED3-7144D9AE90F2}_Large.jpg

./S/Slackers/AlbumArtSmall.jpg
./S/Slackers/AlbumArt_{4CC84D50-8EED-415A-9ED3-7144D9AE90F2}_Small.jpg

./L/Led Zeppelin - Discography/Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin III/AlbumArt_{C9AAD432-BF70-4AFB-97C6-14734CD290B8}_Large.jpg
./L/Led Zeppelin - Discography/Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin III/Folder.jpg
```

Comment: I'd think something from `urllib` would do the trick. See [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960751/encode-file-path-properly-using-python).

Comment: Do you mean escape or encode, e.g. `%20`? If you mean escape, what escape character are you looking for?

Comment: i want the pathnames to be passed as an argument for another function like "commands.getstatusoutput" or "os.system" or something from subprocess. right now it wont work because the path names got whitespaces and other special characters so i cant just pass the names to some subprocess function because bash does not like unescaped special characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`pipes.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) function. In Python 3 this function was renamed to [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote). These functions quote a string so that it can safely be used as part of a shell command.

Comment: I used it with the subprocess.Popen() and could safely pass the file paths with spaces.