# Python - Whitespace in path

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably a really simple issue, but I am having the hardest time with it. I'm trying to execute a command prompt command in Python, but since I have spaces in the path (C:\Program Files\etc) it says that `"C:\Program" is not a recognized command`

So far I have tried to use the escape character backslash `\` to interpret the spaces as actual spaces, but this didn't work. I also tried doing `('"'+chkcmd+'"')` but that didnt work either. Here is the simple code I'm trying to use:

```
chkcmd = "C:\Program Files\whatever.exe"
os.system(chkcmd)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escape whitespaces in linux path and file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844707/escape-whitespaces-in-linux-path-and-file-names)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977215/os-system-to-invoke-an-exe-which-lies-in-a-dir-whose-name-contains-whitespace

Comment: To me `os.system('"'+chkcmd+'"')` seem to work (it complains about `C:\Program Files\whatever.exe` doesn't exist, but that's expected as I don't have that executable here).

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't use single backslash in a string literal to make a backslash - you should use double backslash in order to distinguish it from backslashes used to escape special characters (eg '\n`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a program from python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path)

Comment: I tried both the double backslashes and what skyking mentioned, but neither of them worked. Are there any other ways to make it recognize that there are spaces in the path?

Comment: when you write a windows path use [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=raw#text-sequence-type-str), that way you don need to worry about escapes special characters character. To use it you only nee to append a `r` add the start of the string. For example `r"c:\notepad.exe"`. Now compare both with and without the `r` by printing them

Comment: @Copperfield, so that works... kind of. In this command prompt command, I need to have double quotes after a pipe. So the final command will look like `c:\program files\whatever.exe -version | find "example"` But it is ending the double quotes right before example. So it never gets to the word `example`

Comment: try with `"c:\program files\whatever.exe" -version | find "example"` or `'"c:\program files\whatever.exe" -version | find "example"'` (notice the that is a string build with `'` )